# Iterate over list to perform requests

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, request

I have a list of coordinates, 'coords':

```
[[14.21055347, 47.5674345], [16.39356558, 48.17711001], [14.21055347, 47.5674345], [16.29236955, 48.15006768], [16.32467573, 48.13840484], [16.147533399999997, 48.3067388], [14.502926, 48.19992600000001]]
```

For these coordinates I need to perform requests in pairs of two like that (x, x+1):

```
Pair 1: [[14.21055347, 47.5674345], [16.39356558, 48.17711001]]

Pair 2: [[16.39356558, 48.17711001], [14.21055347, 47.5674345]]

Pair 3: [[14.21055347, 47.5674345], [16.29236955, 48.15006768]]

etc.
```

The request body looks like that:

```
body = {"coordinates":coords,"extra_info":["waycategory"]}

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, application/geo+json, application/gpx+xml, img/png; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Type': 'application/geo+json; charset=utf-8'
}
call = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/ors/v2/directions/driving-hgv/geojson', json=body, headers=headers)

weiter = call.text

data = json.loads(weiter)
```

The above code will use the whole list of coordinates, as defined in "coordinates":coords - now I need to have an iteration over the body for "coordinates":pair1, "coordinates":pair2, etc.

I tried using a for and a while loop, but can't seem to define that e.g. "coordinates":coords[x,x+1]

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: How does your for/while loop look?

Comment: I acutally tried using a counter  i=0 and have it count +1 each time and use that as a location of the list like coords[i:(i+1)] - this obviously did not work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of slicing and the `zip` built-in function could be used to generate the coordinates to be used for each request. E.g.

```
coords = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
coords = zip(coords, coords[1:])
```

Then you can loop over them with e.g.

```
for c1, c2 in coords:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop over the list and create the coordinates with two values.

you can try below code:

```
ls = [[14.21055347, 47.5674345], [16.39356558, 48.17711001], [14.21055347, 47.5674345], [16.29236955, 48.15006768], [16.32467573, 48.13840484], [16.147533399999997, 48.3067388], [14.502926, 48.19992600000001]]
for i in range(len(ls)-1):
    coords = [ls[i],ls[i+1]]
    print(coords)
    your next logic with coords
```

Comment: IndexError in last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
coords = [[14.21055347, 47.5674345], [16.39356558, 48.17711001], [14.21055347, 47.5674345], [16.29236955, 48.15006768], [16.32467573, 48.13840484], [16.147533399999997, 48.3067388], [14.502926, 48.19992600000001]]

# Generate a list of coordinate tuples using list comprehension
pairs = [(coords[i], coords[i+1]) for i in range(len(coords) - 1)]

for pair in pairs:
    body = {"coordinates": pair, "extra_info": ["waycategory"]}

    # Send the request here
```

Here we are using [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to generate a list of coordinate tuples, and then we iterate over the generated tuples.

You can also use the same iteration technique in the for loop if you are not interested in generating the list of coordinate pairs at all.

Comment: range should not have step I think.

Comment: You are correct, I thought the pairs should be separated but just noticed they were not in the example. Good catch

Comment: But now you get IndexError for last iteration.